# query regarding DocumentRoot

Tags: php, apache

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.I am new to PHP and I want to execute ".php" file.I have followed tutorial which says that I should include my php file at the location "/var/www". There is no folder named "www" in my system.I have also used "sudo find / -name www".So what am I missing?how can I find my current document root?
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf - you will find your DocumentRoot there!

Answer (score 0):

I used "grep -i 'DocumentRoot' httpd.conf". and I got location of my DocumentRoot.